# Is the space of bijections on a compact Hausdorff space compact?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space and let $Sym(X)$ be the set of set-theoretic bijections $X \to X$ (need not be continuous). Is $Sym(X) \subset X^X$ a compact subspace? If not, is there a "natural topology" we can give to $Sym(X)$ such that it would be compact?

Comment: If your functions need not be continuous, what's the topology on $X^X$?

Comment: $X^X$ is the set of functions $X \to X$, together with the product topology. By Tychonoff's theorem, $X^X$ is compact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Let $X = \mathbb{N} \cup \{ \infty \}$ be the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{N}$. Consider the following sequence of bijections: $s_n$ assigns the first $n$ positive integers the values $n+1, \dots 2n$, then the next $n$ positive integers the values $1, \dots n$, then fixes all larger positive integers and $\infty$. This sequence of bijections converges pointwise (this is convergence in the product topology) to the function with constant value $\infty$, which is not a bijection.

Generally speaking one expects invertible maps to be open in the space of all maps rather than closed; the prototypical example here is $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ being an open subspace of $M_n(\mathbb{R})$. More generally the invertible elements of a Banach algebra are an open subspace.

**Edit:** As for the second question, here is a more complicated counterexample. Let $X$ be the one-point compactification of a set of size strictly larger than the continuum. $\text{Sym}(X)$ contains as a subgroup $\text{Sym}_f(X)$, the set of permutations which fix all but finitely many elements; this subgroup has a further subgroup $\text{Alt}_f(X)$ of alternating permutations, which is known to be simple.

Now, by the [Peter-Weyl theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter%E2%80%93Weyl_theorem), any compact Hausdorff topological group has the property that its points are separated by finite-dimensional unitary representations, in the sense that given $g, h \in G$ there exists a continuous homomorphism $\rho : G \to U(n)$ for some $n$ such that $\rho(g) \neq \rho(h)$. But $\text{Alt}_f(X)$ is a simple group with cardinality strictly larger than the cardinality of any $U(n)$, so it admits no nonzero such homomorphisms. We conclude that $\text{Sym}(X)$ cannot be given any compact Hausdorff topology whatsoever making it a topological group.

Comment: One of my favorite memories from first year grad school was to show the invertible operators were open in a finite dimensional case.  My fellow students did all kinds of complicated arguments, I just noted it was the preimage of the the underlying field less 0 under the continuous determinant map :)

Comment: @Alan: it's a clean argument but of course it doesn't generalize to the Banach algebra case. It builds character to find an alternative argument that stands a better chance of generalizing, I think!

Comment: Yeah, I later worked on the general case when I studied more functional analysis.